# Question / answer "buddies": to what end?

Tags: discussion

I've raised a moderator flag on this already, but I'm also just curious — what purpose is served by this curious activity, where two users have obviously prearranged a question-answer game (pointed out by user @dfri, so all credit to his research):

[Links in WKWebView randomly not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693311/links-in-wkwebview-randomly-not-clickable/)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273822/facebook-post-using-slrequest-change-the-post-audience

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949962/caemitterlayer-use-custom-shape

[Give iOS app permanent permission to post to Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218638/give-ios-app-permanent-permission-to-post-to-facebook)

[Getting width of the Notification-Center inside Today-Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085840/getting-width-of-the-notification-center-inside-today-extension)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086966/swift-3-parameterless-initializer-will-be-removed-warning

Comment: to get rep.... simple. Terrible way to go at it, but yeah

Comment: Your fourth link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218638/give-ios-app-permanent-permission-to-post-to-facebook does not seem to have any activity by the "return true" account.

Comment: It's not that curious.  It's not even uncommon. Every time you see a question that is easily answered with a trivial Google, but has one or more upvoted answers and a quick accept, then you are probably looking at yet another voting-ring fraud.  It explains how so many grossly-incompetent users get so much rep.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, but he is partnered by the same questioner "return false" elsewhere. So they are all of a piece. Again, keep in mind they are not my links; this was all pointed out by user dfri (who also raised a moderator flag, he tells me).

Comment: My naiveté about ways to gain rep must be the laughing-stock of the SO universe. "What, you actually waste time trying to _help_ people?"

Comment: Given that you're #173 out of 5 million users by rep, @matt, it seems that being helpful may still be the best way.

Comment: I can see how they can gain rep by upvoting each other's posts. But what is the use of all the bounties? One of them loses just as much rep as the other gains, or am I wrong about this?

Comment: Well, it is a cheat to not lose rep on a bounty.  Perceived anyway.  They are getting larsoned right now.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Yes, and that's how they got caught: the question / answer pair were _so_ low-quality in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086966/swift-3-parameterless-initializer-will-be-removed-warning that they were both downright false. And it was a matter which, had it been true, would have been alarming. That is what raised suspicions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell But meet me after school, I think I have an idea how we can _both_ increase our reps.

Comment: This case seemed to involve both some low-quality posts and some weird rep transfer going on using bounties, both of which were good to crack down on, but I'd caution not to be *automatically* hostile towards users posting the two halves of a pre-written Q&A. Perhaps they solved an interesting problem together that they thought the rest of the programming world could benefit from reading about, and - in the absence of a better way to share credit - had one post the Q and the other the A. That would be helpful, unobjectionable behaviour and wouldn't trouble me even if they upvoted each other.

Comment: @HansPassant "getting larsoned" oh lawd

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That's clear voting coordination between two users. Friends sometimes think they can coordinate votes between their accounts to boost each other's reputation and to prevent each other from hitting a question ban. It usually doesn't work out well for them in the end.

The targeted bounties are a way of transferring reputation to avoid reputation caps and other system-imposed limits. They also are an effective means of boosting votes on questions and answers, due to the increased visibility of bountied questions.

I've deleted the bountied answers to remove the bounties, warned the users involved, and requested manual invalidation of all votes. That'll undo anything they've gained by this, and should get the point across.

Comment: Cool, thx as always. — You don't have to reply to this (and you shouldn't, if it gives away important secrets): I wonder if/how they would have been caught if not for the clever detective work of @dfri.

Comment: @matt - Hypothetically, you might imagine that moderators would have tools that point out anomalous voting patterns between specific users and that we would act on these as we came across them. Beyond that, there are queries users and moderators occasionally run to pull out accounts that only tend to answer questions from other accounts. That alone would have identified these two. We break up a number of voting rings every week.

Comment: 0.O how does one become such a god in the Overflow?

Comment: @RichardBarker For users, there's the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, moderators have tools already provided for them.